# AspxPivotGrid Group column header

Tags: asp.net, grid, devexpress

I want to be able to add a parent column header to each pair of columns shown below.

[image]

So I want it to look like this:

```
       Grand Total
    OnHand    Available
```

[image]

Anyone know a way to do this? I know you can group columns together but I'm wondering how I can apply a label to those groups.

Alternatively, if theres no way to do that, I could just override the "Grand Total" display text. The only problem is I can't get it aligned above its correct columns.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no solution, it is impossible to achieve this layout :(.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is have a table with the fields you need for example:

ID: 1
typeColumn: "Grand Total"
OnHand : 1000
Available : 2000

So:

```
<dx:aspxpivotgrid ID = "pivotGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumn = "False">
    <fields>
        <dx:PivotGridField Area="ColumnArea" AreaIndex="0" Caption="Grand Total" FieldName="typeColumn" Visible = "True"/>

        <dx:PivotGridField Area="DataArea" AreaIndex="0" Caption="Montos" FieldName="OnHand"
                        ID="fieldMontos" SummaryType="Max" />

        <dx:PivotGridField Area="DataArea" AreaIndex="1" Caption="%" FieldName="Available"
                        ID="fieldPjes" SummaryType="Max"  />
    </fields>
</dx:aspxpivotgrid>
```